# How can I use as a sequence of alternating keys and values to define a Bash 5.1 associative array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I read in the [release notes of Bash 5.1](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS):

> gg. Associative arrays may be assigned using a list of key-value pairs within a compound assignment. Compound assignments where the words are not of the form [key]=value are assumed to be key-value assignments. A missing or empty key is an error; a missing value is treated as NULL. Assignments may not mix the two forms.

Checking on the [Bash 5.1 Reference Manual → Arrays section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) I see this new block (comparing to the [Bash 4.4 Reference Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426040945/https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays)):

> When assigning to an associative array, the words in a compound assignment may be either assignment statements, for which the subscript is required, or a list of words that is interpreted as a sequence of alternating keys and values: `name=(key1 value1 key2 value2 … )`. These are treated identically to `name=( [key1]=value1 [key2]=value2 … )`. The first word in the list determines how the remaining words are interpreted; all assignments in a list must be of the same type. When using key/value pairs, the keys may not be missing or empty; a final missing value is treated like the empty string.
>
> This syntax is also accepted by the declare builtin. Individual array elements may be assigned to using the `name[subscript]=value` syntax introduced above.

So I did a test:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0)
$ declare -a bla
$ bla=( [name]=me )
$ echo "${bla[name]}"
me      # it works well
```

However, if I use the new syntax it does not work to me and it returns me the key instead of the value:

```
$ declare -a bla
$ ble=( name me )
$ echo "${ble[name]}"
name      # should be "me"
```

How can I properly use the compound assignment as a sequence of alternating keys and values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a matter of defining the associative array with `declare -A` (note the capital letter for "A"):

```
declare -A bla
$ bla=(k1 v1 k2 v2)
$ echo "${bla[k1]}"
v1
```

If you try to mix assignations, it fails as indicated:

```
$ bla=([k1]=v1 k2 v2)
bash: bla: k2: must use subscript when assigning associative array
bash: bla: v2: must use subscript when assigning associative array
$ bla=([k1]=v1 [k2]=v2)
$ echo "${bla[k2]}"
v2
```

Comment: also note that: `(LANG=C; unset assoc; declare -A assoc; assoc+=(k1 v1))` just fail.

Comment: @LéaGris it works well to me: `(LANG=C; unset assoc; declare -A assoc; assoc+=(k1 v1); echo "${assoc[k1]}")` produces "v1"

Comment: here Bash 5.0.17\(1)-release \(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Getting: `bash: assoc: k1: must use subscript when assigning associative array
bash: assoc: v1: must use subscript when assigning associative array
`

Comment: My bad I realize it is only valid for Bash 5.1+. I guess we will have to wait a decade or two until we can rely on this to translate a key value file in one go into an associative array, like `mapfile -t array keyvaluefile.txt; declare -A assoc=("${array[@]}")`