# What is the use of the "@a" operator on shell expansions?

Tags: bash

I read in the [release notes of Bash 5.1](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS) these the interesting items:

> z. The `@a' variable transformation now prints attributes for unset array variables.

> aa. The `@A' variable transformation now prints a declare command that sets a variable's attributes if the variable has attributes but is unset.

So let's check how they work. Firstly, with  Bash 4.3 to see the progression and see they used to produce the same:

```
$ declare -A arra=([k1]="v1" [k2]="v2" [k3]="")
$ echo "${arra[@]@a}"
v1 v2
$ echo "${arra[@]@A}"
v1 v2
```

Now with Bash 5.1 using a [sequence of alternating keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65219055/1983854):

```
$ declare -A arra=(k1 v2 k2 v2 k3)
$ echo "${arra[@]@a}"
A A A
$ echo "${arra[@]@A}"
declare -A arra=([k1]="v1" [k2]="v2" [k3]="" )
```

So `@A` is useful to see the definition of the array, whereas `@a` gives an "A" for every associative value. Does it?
Checking on the [Bash 5.1 Reference Manual → Arrays section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) says:

> `${parameter@operator}`
>
> **a**
> The expansion is a string consisting of flag values representing parameter’s attributes.

But I don't see what else apart form an "A" can come as an output. If I use it against a normal variable, it does not produce anything:

```
$ v=1
$ echo "${v@a}"
                  # nothing
$ v="hello"
$ echo "${v@a}"
                  # nothing
```

Comment: you will see other-than-`A` output with, e.g., `declare -i v=1` or `declare -l v="Hello"`, and also for exported variables: `declare -x v=1` which can have its uses.

Comment: and in fact for all the flags (except `-n`): `for f in a A i l n r t u x; do (declare -$f v; echo "$f: ${v@a}"); done`. For a variable reference, `@a` will show the target's flag: `declare -i a=1; declare -n v=a; echo "${v@a}"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf oh, interesting. So we can have "A" for associative array, "i" for integer, "il" for...?, "a" for array, and "x" for...

Comment: Yes, `il` is interesting `:)`. The flags will combine in interesting (and inconsistent) ways (run the command I gave in the previous comment, without the subshell for `declare`).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf quite nice! Some do not work together if I use `for f in a A i l n r t u x; do declare -$f v; echo "$f: ${v@a}"; done` and I am also prompted an error "bash: declare: `1': invalid variable name for name reference". In any case, what you commented is quite good information that qualifies as an excellent answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will see other flags than `A` when the variables have been `declare`'d with these flags:

```
$ declare -i v
$ echo "${v@a}"
i
$
```

`declare` knows about these flags: `a`, `A`, `i`, `l`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `u` and `x` (see `help declare` for the descriptions). Here's a little snippet to see that in action (done in a new session, or `unset v` before):

```
$ unset v
$ for f in a A i l n r t u x; do (declare -$f v; echo "$f: ${v@a}"); done
a: a
A: A
i: i
l: l
n: 
r: r
t: t
u: u
x: x
$
```

Something's happening with `-n` (a reference). In this case, Bash will return the flag of the target:

```
$ declare -i a
$ declare -n v=a
$ echo "${v@a}"
i
$
```

As noticed in the OP comments, the flags can combine in weird and inconsistent ways:

```
$ # declaring integer AND lowercase
$ declare -il v
$ echo "${v@a}"
il
$ # ???
```

---

And just for fun: removing the subshell for `declare` (so that the flags combine) in the previous snippet:

```
$ unset v
$ for f in a A i l n r t u x; do declare -$f v; echo "$f: ${v@a}"; done
a: a
bash: declare: v: cannot convert indexed to associative array
A: a
i: ai
l: ail
bash: declare: v: reference variable cannot be an array
n: ail
r: airl
t: airtl
u: airtu
x: airtxu
$
```

(I did this for fun only, not to show anything special other than some quirky corners of Bash).

Comment: You could even point to the relevant [bash manual, section 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): `${parameter@operator}` The expansion is either a transformation of the value of parameter or information about parameter itself, depending on the value of operator. Each operator is a single letter